# Python: изменить строку согласно правилу

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть список правил и строка. Мне нужно создать новую строку, представляющую собой первоначальную строку, измененную согласно одному из правил (выбирается случайно). Я могу это сделать 6-ю выражениями с `if`, но как-то хочется придумать более элегантный и общий способ.

```
from random import choice

vowels = ['а', 'и', 'о', 'у']
consonants = ['н', 'з', 'г', 'ш', 'р', 'т', 'б', 'к', 'х']

rules = ['cVc', 'Cvc', 'cVC', 'CVc', 'cvC', 'CvC']
currentString = 'гор'
```

Каждое правило из `rules` представляет собой схему `currentString`, в которой `с` значит согласную, `v` - гласную, а высокий регистр обозначает, какую букву в `currentString` нужно заменить на случайную. То есть:

- если мы возьмем первое правило `cVc`, то на выходе должно получиться `newString = 'г' + choice(vowels) + 'р'`
- а если последнее правило `CvC`, то `newString = choice(consonants) + 'о' + choice(consonants)`.

У кого какие идеи? Было бы оч здорово, если бы кто-нибудь указал бы на метод решения, а не на готовый код, т.к. это помогло бы в обучении. Спасибо!

Edit: с помощью гугла допер до следующего решения:

```
def newString(currentString):
    rules = ['cVc', 'Cvc', 'cVC', 'CVc', 'cvC', 'reverse']
    rule = choice(rules)

    if rule == 'reverse':
        return currentString[::-1]
    
    else:
        rule_list = list(rule)
        currentString_list = list(currentString)

        for index, character in enumerate(rule_list):
            if character.isupper() and character == 'V':
                currentString_list[index] = choice(vowels)
            if character.isupper() and character == 'C':
                currentString_list[index] = choice(orkishCons)
        return ''.join(currentString_list)
```

Comment: откуда вы вообще такие задачи берете -_-

Comment: Приведите код с 6 ифами, чтобы было понятно, что ожидается в результате

Comment: Что делать, если в currentString на месте гласной будет согласная?

Comment: `result = ''.join([c if r.islower() else random.choice(vowels if r == 'V' else consonants) for r, c in zip(rule, currentString)])`

Comment: А что если правило `vvv`, а строка `шшш`. нужно ли что-нибудь заменять или выдать ошибку? Что делать если строка `аоу`, а правило `vCv`, нужно ли заменять гласную `о` на случайную согласную? Что если строка `ыэё`?

Comment: @extrn нет, input (то есть currentString) генерируется именно в этом формате: согласная, гласная, согласная

Comment: @whizz169 я пытаюсь сделать генератор оркских имен для днд группы

Comment: @dIm0n сделал эдит в посте

Answer (score 1):

Можно не рассматривать каждое правило отдельно, а составлять итоговую строку в цикле, на каждой итерации которого обрабатывать очередной символ. Это позволить укоротить код и даст возможность легко увеличивать количество и длину правил.

```
from random import choice

vowels = ['а', 'и', 'о', 'у']
consonants = ['н', 'з', 'г', 'ш', 'р', 'т', 'б', 'к', 'х']

rules = ['cVc', 'Cvc', 'cVC', 'CVc', 'cvC', 'CvC']
currentString = 'гор'

res = ''
rule = choice(rules)

for cur, r in zip(currentString, rule):
    if r.islower():
        res += cur
    elif r == 'C':
        res += choice(consonants)
    else:
        res += choice(vowels)

print(rule, currentString, res, sep='\n')
```

https://ideone.com/X4W3Y4